# What does this error mean for this massive postgresql statement in a Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following massive sql statement executing in a Rails 4 application via the usual ActiveRecord query helpers (where, join)..Products are distinguished via unique database id.

```
SELECT
    subscriptions.braintree_account_id as braintree_account_id,
    subscriptions.braintree_subscription_id as braintree_subscription_id,
    format('%s %s', addresses.first_name, addresses.last_name) as shipping_address_full_name,
    users.email as email,
    addresses.line_1 as shipping_address_line_1,
    addresses.line_2 as shipping_address_line_2,
    addresses.city as shipping_address_city,
    addresses.state as shipping_address_state,
    addresses.zip as shipping_address_zip_code,
    addresses.country as shipping_address_country,
    CASE WHEN tiger_shirt IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_shirt END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_socks IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_socks END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_accessories IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_accessories END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_waist IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_waist END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_tail_shirt IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_tail_shirt END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_tail_socks IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_tail_socks END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_tail_waist IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_tail_waist END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_tshirt IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_tshirt END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_accessories_waist IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_accessories_waist END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_ta_tail_shirt IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_ta_tail_shirt END,
    CASE WHEN tiger_ta_tail_waist IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_ta_tail_waist END,
    plans.name as plan_name,
    products.sku as sku,
    to_char(subscriptions.created_at, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') as subscription_created_at,
    to_char(subscriptions.next_assessment_at, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') as subscription_next_assessment_at,
    subscriptions.subscription_status as subscription_status
FROM
    "subscriptions"
INNER JOIN
    "addresses"
    ON "addresses"."id" = "subscriptions"."shipping_address_id"
    AND "addresses"."type" IN ('ShippingAddress')
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    shipping_methods
    ON shipping_methods.subscription_id = subscriptions.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    plans
    ON subscriptions.plan_id = plans.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    users
    ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    products
    ON plans.product_id = products.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM crosstab('SELECT
                                subscriptions.id,
                                choice_types.id,
                                value_choices.presentation
                            FROM
                                subscriptions
                            LEFT JOIN
                                subscription_variables
                                ON subscriptions.id = subscription_variables.subscription_id
                            LEFT JOIN
                                variables
                                ON subscription_variables.variable_id=variables.id
                            LEFT JOIN
                                value_choice_variables
                                ON variables.id=value_choice_variables.variable_id
                            LEFT JOIN
                                value_choices
                                ON value_choice_variables.value_choice_id=value_choices.id
                            LEFT JOIN
                                choice_types
                                ON value_choices.choice_type_id=choice_types.id
                            LEFT JOIN
                                choice_type_products
                                ON choice_type_products.choice_type_id=choice_types.id
                            LEFT JOIN
                                products
                                ON choice_type_products.product_id = products.id
                            WHERE
                                products.id IN (2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 15)
                            ORDER BY 1,2',
                            'SELECT
                                choice_types.id
                            FROM
                                choice_types
                            JOIN
                                choice_type_products
                                ON choice_type_products.choice_type_id = choice_types.id
                            JOIN
                                products
                                ON choice_type_products.product_id = products.id
                            WHERE
                                products.id IN (2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 15)
                            ORDER BY
                                choice_types.id ASC')
                            AS (
                                subscription_id int,
                                tiger_shirt VARCHAR,
                                tiger_socks VARCHAR,
                                tiger_accessories VARCHAR,
                                tiger_waist VARCHAR,
                                tiger_tail_shirt VARCHAR,
                                tiger_tail_waist VARCHAR,
                                tiger_tail_socks VARCHAR,
                                tiger_tshirt VARCHAR,
                                tiger_accessories_waist VARCHAR,
                                tiger_ta_tail_shirt VARCHAR,
                                tiger_ta_tail_waist VARCHAR
                                )
    ) subscription_variable_view
    ON subscriptions.id=subscription_variable_view.subscription_id
    WHERE
        "subscriptions"."subscription_status" = $1 AND
        "addresses"."flagged_invalid_at" IS NULL AND
        "products"."id" IN (2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 15) AND
        (NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                "subscription_hunted_months".*
            FROM
                "subscription_hunted_months"
            WHERE
                "subscription_hunted_months"."month_year" = 'JUN2016' AND
                subscription_hunted_months.subscription_id = subscriptions.id))
```

I get the following error when it tries to run...what does it mean?  And what could be causing it?

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR:  duplicate category name
```

Comment: BTW - Instead of writing out all of this: `CASE WHEN tiger_shirt IS NULL THEN '' ELSE tiger_shirt END`, you can simply use `COALESCE` like so: `COALESCE(tiger_shirt,'')`

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your `CATEGORY` SQL argument is returning duplicate values:

```
SELECT
    choice_types.id
FROM
    choice_types
JOIN
    choice_type_products
    ON choice_type_products.choice_type_id = choice_types.id
JOIN
    products
    ON choice_type_products.product_id = products.id
WHERE
    products.id IN (2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 15)
ORDER BY
    choice_types.id ASC
```

If you simply made it `DISTINCT` and reran you query - it may resolve the issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    choice_types.id
    ...
```

Comment: Sadly, that didn't seem to work, but I appreciate the assist....upvoting